# Filtering out null values from where clause

Tags: sql, abap

I have a pretty simple select:

```
select * from ZMM_TABLE
  into CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF table lt_table
  where mjahr = p_mjahr and
        werks = p_werks and
```

...

when p_values are presented - everything is ok. There's a half a dozen of it, so the problem - how to use only those which are filled by user. And i can't make it obligatory and require to fill all of that fields. 
I thought about case statement, but there's too much combinations possible. How should i solve that better as simple as possible?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to filter on some fields, and if the filter is empty, any value for that field is valid.

The best option is to build the query as necessary. For example, if the user inputs "p_mjahr", but not "p_werks", you issue create a query like...

```
select * from ZMM_TABLE
  into CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF table lt_table
  where mjahr = p_mjahr
```

If this is not possible, you can do this:

```
select * from ZMM_TABLE
  into CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF table lt_table
  where (mjahr = p_mjahr or p_mjahr = '') and
        (werks = p_werks or p_werks = '') and
```

The way this query works is, if p_mjahr has a value, the second argument to the "or" will be false, but the first one will match as expected. However, if p_mjahr is `''` (the empty string), the second argument of the `or` clause will be `true`, making the whole clause `true`. Further filters, through the `and` will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, i think the second one should work just fine... Oops, except it didn't. Error - p_mjahr isn't a table column.

Answer (score 1):

First: Be aware that `NULL` values and empty fields are two entirely different things. `NULL` values in ABAP applications are relatively uncommon and need to be treated with the `IS [NOT] NULL` statement.

Assuming that you really mean empty fields, not `NULL` values: Use selection tables, but use the canonical way to define them and if possible the modern way to fill them:

```
DATA: lt_range_whatever TYPE RANGE OF datatype_here.

lt_range_whatever = value #( ( sign = 'I' option = 'EQ' low = 'value' ) ).

SELECT foo, bar
  FROM baz
  INTO wherever
  WHERE whatever IN @lt_range_whatever.
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, i've found another way to accomplish that. Used statement like this:

```
    select-OPTIONS: s_mjahr for ZMM_TABLE-mjahr no-EXTENSION
                    no INTERVALS,
...


 select * from ZMM_TABLE
  into CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF table lt_table
  where  mjahr in s_mjahr  and
         werks in s_werks and ... so on.
```

Comment: If that is what you were after, you should have stated that you wanted a selection screen in the first place. How should we know?

Answer (score -1):

Use [selection tables' syntax](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abenwhere_logexp_seltab.htm) instead. In order to use them you must declare range table like this:

```
DATA: BEGIN OF rtab OCCURS {10|n}, 
    sign   TYPE c LENGTH 1, 
    option TYPE c LENGTH 2, 
    low    LIKE dobj, 
    high   LIKE dobj, 
  END OF rtab.
```

They are to be filled like that:

```
rtab-sign = 'I'.
rtab-options = 'EQ'.
rtab-low = p_mjahr.
rtab-high = p_mjahr.
APPEND rtab.
```

If the selection table is initial, the expression `IN seltab` is always true.

Comment: This answer is advocating obsolete syntax elements. Avoid picking up this style.

Answer (score -2):

What datatype are p_values?

this example will work if they are int and mjahr and werks can not have value 0 (zero):

```
select * from ZMM_TABLE
  into CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF table lt_table
  where mjahr = isnull(p_mjahr,0) and
        werks = isnull(p_werks,0) and
```

Comment: Different types, but mostly char.

Comment: As far as I can see, `isnull( )` is not a valid statement in ABAP Open SQL.

Comment: you can use same logic, and adopt the code according to ABAB Open SQL syntax, as i noticed Tordek already did that